# Can I overload methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Example:

I want to have two different constructors, and I don't want to use func_get_arg(), because then it's invisible what args are possible.

Is it legal to write two of them, like:

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct() {
    // do something
    }
    public function __construct(array $arg) {
    // do something
    }
}
```

?

Comment: A minor issue, but __construct(array $arg) isn't valid - you don't specify types in PHP.

Comment: sure you can do that. It's called type hinting.

Comment: @middaparka: it's totally valid: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Damn - my bad - you can do this since PHP 5.1. (You live and learn.) :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct($arg = null) {
        if(is_array($arg)) {
            // do something with the array
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

In PHP, a function can receive any number of arguments, and they don't have to be defined if you give them a default value. This is how you can 'fake' function overloading and allow access to functions with different arguments.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has something that it calls "overloading" (via the [`__call`](http://php.net/__call#language.oop5.overloading.methods) magic method), but what really happens is the magic method `__call` is invoked when an inaccessible or non-existent method, rather like `__get` and `__set` let you "access" inaccessible/non-existent properties. You could use this to implement overloading of non-magic methods, but it's unwieldy.

As formal parameters can be untyped (which is distinct from the argument values being untyped, since those *are* typed) and even function arity isn't strictly enforced (each function has a minimum number of arguments, but no theoretical maximum), you could also write the method body to handle different number and types of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't do that.

Comment: +1 This guy - http://www.php.net/manual/en/overload.examples.basic.php#95254 - provides the elaboration :)

Comment: but he also says, unless it's not type hinted ;) what sucks about func_get_args is that it just sucks. As a framework user you'll not get helpful information about what params you can provide. oh man. this really sucks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, however to solve the problem of invisible args, you can use the [reflection class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php).

```
if(count($args) == 0)
  $obj = new $className;
else {
 $r = new ReflectionClass($className);
 $obj = $r->newInstanceArgs($args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the PHP is a weak-typing language and it supports functions with variable number of the arguments (so-called varargs) there is no difference to processor between two functions with the same name even they have different number of declared arguments (all functions are varargs). So, the overloading is illegal by design.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to create pseudo-overloaded functions, though that may cause a confusing interface for your method/function.