# Overloading construct in php?

Tags: php, oop

does php (5.3.7) supports overloading ?

Example:

```
class myclass{

function __construct($arg1) { // Construct with 1 param}
function __construct($arg1,$arg2) { // Construct with 2 param}

}


new myclass(123); //> call the first construct
new myclass(123,'abc'); //> call the second
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985182/can-i-overload-methods-in-php

Comment: Current stable version is 5.3.5, are you asking about latest development snapshots?

Comment: @alvaro: what's the difference?

Comment: with PHP 5.3.7 not being released yet, the only correct answer is: we cannot know. But since current versions of PHP do not support this, it is unlikely that any PHP 5.3.7 will.

Comment: PHP/5.3.7 does not exist. If you are asking whether you can do it *now*, the question is already answered (see @bazmegakapa's link). If you are asking whether PHP is planning overloading for future releases, the question is entirely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement the constructor once and use `func_get_args` and `func_num_args` like this:

```
<?php

class myclass {
    function __construct() {
        $args = func_get_args();

        switch (func_num_args()) {
            case 1:
                var_dump($args[0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                var_dump($args[0], $args[1]);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Wrong number of arguments passed to the constructor of myclass");
        }
    }
}

new myclass(123); //> call the first construct
new myclass(123,'abc'); //> call the second
new myclass(123,'abc','xyz'); //> will throw an exception
```

This way you can support any number of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

No, but it supports [optional parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), or [variable number of parameters](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php).

```
class myclass{
  function __construct($arg1, $arg2 = null){
    if($arg2 === null){ // construct with 1 param //}
    else{ // construct with 2 param //}
  }
}
```

*Note that this has the downside that if you actually want to be able to supply `null` as a second parameter it will not accept it. But in the remote case you want that you can always use the `func_*` family of utils.*

Answer (score 0):

I would define some `fromXXX` methods that call the `__constructor` which takes a parameter like `id`.

```php
<?php
class MyClass {
   public function __construct(int $id) {
       $instance = Database::getByID($id);
       $this->foo = $instance['foo'];
       $this->bar = $instance['bar'];
   }
   public static function fromFoo(string $foo): MyClass {
       $id = Database::find('foo', $foo);
       return new MyClass($id);
   }
}
```